# PHP not working in google app engine with app.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm making an HTML website using google app engine. I have a contact form in my index.html which calls on send_mail.php to send an email. The problem is when I click on send it asks me download the php. Is there a way to fix this. Here's my app.yaml file

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: assets/index.html
  upload: assets/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: assets
```

The code of my html file is a normal contact form

```
 <form class="form" id="form1" action="send_mail.php" method="post">
  <p>
  <input name="name" type="text"  id="name" />
  </p>
  <p>
 <input name="email" type="text"  id="email"  />
  </p>
    <p>
 <input name="email" type="text"  id="sub" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <textarea name="text"  id="comments" placeholder="الرسالة"></textarea>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="ارسل" id="button-pink"/>
  </font>
  </form>
```

and my php file looks like this

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "xyz@hotmail.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$index = "index.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$name = $_REQUEST ['name']
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$sub = $_REQUEST ['sub']
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $index" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Contact Form", "Subject: $sub",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the code in your index.html file look like, not to mention the send_mail.php?

Comment: I've added the code in  index.html and send_mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a url handler for `send_mail.php`, like:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: assets/\1
```

That serves all `somefile.php` scripts.  Or, hard code this one script, as:

```
- url: /send_mail.php
  script: assets/send_mail.php
```

Comment: I added - url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: assets/send_mail.php\1  still doesnt work.

Comment: That is not what I wrote.  You want `script: assets/\1`

Comment: does it work on localhost? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Yes, it works on localhost.  Is send_mail.php inside your assets folder? Is it giving you an error?